# How to count the number of times a value changes, grouped by two variables in R

Tags: r, grouping, cumsum

I have a dataframe similar to the constructed one below, but much larger.

```
id <- rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each = 3)
date <- seq(as.Date("2019-01-27"), as.Date("2019-02-7"), by="days")
mode <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2)
month <- c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb")
data <- data.frame(id, date, mode, month)
data <- data %>% arrange(id, date)
```

I would like to count the amount of times the value in "mode" column changes, but grouped by id and month. I know I can count the number of times a variable switches with no group using this line below:

```
data$mode.switches <- cumsum(c(0,as.numeric(diff(data$mode))!=0))
```

But I need to incorporate grouping and cannot figure that aspect out. I tried utilizing `dplyr`:

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(id, month) %>%
  mutate(mode.switches = cumsum(c(0,as.numeric(diff(data$mode))!=0))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

But that produces an error "mode.switches must be size 3 or 1, not 12."
I also know I could separate the dataframe into a list of unique combinations of id and month and apply the function over the whole list, but my real dataframe would produce a list with ~3,000 elements, so I would prefer to avoid that.
How can I perform this function over groups determined by two variables in a concise way?
I would appreciate any help on this query!

Comment: Don't use `data$` inside `dplyr` functions. Change `data$mode` (the whole mode column including all groups) to `mode` (the mode column within the current group) and your code should work fine.

Comment: What an easy solution, that worked. Thanks so much.